# Does Family Sharing allow others to see the free Apps that you've downloaded?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, ios-appstore, family-sharing

Does Family Sharing allow others to see the free Apps that you've downloaded or is it just the paid Apps?

I did search online but couldn't seem to find confirmation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but not without looking.

More specifically to your iPhone scenario, to see what has been downloaded by a *family member*, you would need to follow the steps outlined below.

**App Store**

- Go into the App Store app
- tap on Updates at bottom right
- tap on Purchased at top of screen
- a list of family members will appear
- tap on the family member to view their purchases

Note that by purchases we mean **all downloads**, as free apps are effectively treated as though they were *purchased* for $0.00.

**iTunes**

A similar process is required to view their music, movie and other iTunes purchases:

- Go into the iTunes app
- Tap on the More icon at bottom right
- Tap on Purchased
- a list of family members will appear
- tap on the family member to view their purchases

Once again, by purchases we mean **all downloads**.

**iBooks**

And, with iBooks:

- Go into the iBooks app
- Tap on the Purchased icon at bottom right
- a list of family members will appear
- tap on the family member to view their purchases

Once again, by purchases we mean **all downloads**.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I just checked this. All purchases, even free ones, will be displayed.

The same is true for other content bought/downloaded with your Apple ID (e.g. macOS apps, music, movies, books (iBooks store) and audiobooks).